# Get key values of JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have a `org.json.JSONObject` that have multiple levels of values stored inside it. I need to get all the key values of that object but I only able to get the 1st level key values using an `Iterator` is there a way I can access all the levels to get key values.

```
JSONObject jSONObject = XML.toJSONObject(fileContent.toString());
Iterator i = jSONObject.keys();
while (i.hasNext()) {
     System.out.println(i.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONObject [keys](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys%28%29) method. From the javadoc :

> public java.util.Iterator keys() 
>             Get an enumeration of the keys of the JSONObject.
>
> Returns: An iterator of the keys.

Comment: I've used iterator as I posted above. It only returns one level of keys. but I have multiple level of keys inside my JSONObject